# Jtable not showing data after adding all in a baund observablelist

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable, observablelist

I am having some difficult on a jtable bound on a observablelist of objects called EntradaMercadoriaList. After adding all objects in this list, jtable shows only empty rows equivalent of the list size

here is my code:

```
List <EntradaMercadoria> merc = new ArrayList<EntradaMercadoria>();
        for (int i = 0; i < entradasList.size(); i++) {

            int nf = entradasList.get(i).getDocOrigem();
            int tipo = entradasList.get(i).getTipoDocOrigem().getIdesPecasTipoOrigem();
            String fornecedor = "não-aplicado";
            if (tipo == 2) {
                NfTerc nfTerc;
                nfTerc = entityManager.find(NfTerc.class, entradasList.get(i).getDocOrigem());
                fornecedor = nfTerc.getFornecedoresNumForn().getNumForn() + " - " + nfTerc.getFornecedoresNumForn().getCodPessoa().getNomePessoa();
            }
            boolean novo = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < merc.size(); j++) {
                if (nf == merc.get(j).getnDoc() && fornecedor.equals(merc.get(j).getFornecedor())) {
                    merc.get(j).setQuantidade(merc.get(j).getQuantidade() + 1.00);
                    novo = false;
                }
            }
            if (novo) {
                EntradaMercadoria em = new EntradaMercadoria();
                em.setDataEmissao(entradasList.get(i).getDataOrigem());
                em.setFornecedor(fornecedor);
                em.setQuantidade(1.00);
                em.setTipoDoc(tipo);
                em.setnDoc(nf);
                merc.add(em);
            }

        }
        entradaMercadoriaList.clear();
        entradaMercadoriaList.addAll(merc);
```

Here is my EntadaMercadoria object:

```
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author Bernardo
 */
class EntradaMercadoria {

    private int nDoc;
    private int tipoDoc;
    private String fornecedor;
    private double quantidade;
    private Date dataEmissao;

    public EntradaMercadoria() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the nDoc
     */
    public int getnDoc() {
        return nDoc;
    }

    /**
     * @param nDoc the nDoc to set
     */
    public void setnDoc(int nDoc) {
        this.nDoc = nDoc;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tipoDoc
     */
    public int getTipoDoc() {
        return tipoDoc;
    }

    /**
     * @param tipoDoc the tipoDoc to set
     */
    public void setTipoDoc(int tipoDoc) {
        this.tipoDoc = tipoDoc;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fornecedor
     */
    public String getFornecedor() {
        return fornecedor;
    }

    /**
     * @param fornecedor the fornecedor to set
     */
    public void setFornecedor(String fornecedor) {
        this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
    }

    /**
     * @return the quantidade
     */
    public double getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    /**
     * @param quantidade the quantidade to set
     */
    public void setQuantidade(double quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dataEmissao
     */
    public Date getDataEmissao() {
        return dataEmissao;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataEmissao the dataEmissao to set
     */
    public void setDataEmissao(Date dataEmissao) {
        this.dataEmissao = dataEmissao;
    }
}
```

What is wrong? is There a way to refresh table to show data in lines?

Thanks.

Comment: What `TableModel` are you using? Consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). In the code you provided you don't have an observable list, your list must be in an observable component such a `model` as a bound property of the `tableModel` and when you call `setList` then you fire state change to observers.

Comment: There is no declared model, I made it with netbeans and used this jtable bound with an obsersableList...